# Ftest function vs linest function in excel

Tags: statistics

I was confused why the f-test from Ftest function and linest are different when i was trying to do a f-test in excel. Can someone help me explain what is the difference between the two functions?

Not sure why f-test results are different for both methods.

Thank you!